# Find out if application has been scheduled to run using CeRunAppAtTime

Tags: winapi, windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6

I have an application that after it finishes doing it's work schedules itself to run again after x minutes using CeRunAppAtTime.

It has come to our attention that if users are also manually running the application then we can end up with the application being scheduled to run at several times in the future.

Is it possible to get a list of applications that are scheduled to run and remove them?

I have tried searching for this but have not had any success but I'm not sure of what I should be searching for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `CeRunAppAtTime` - it can't do what you want.  Instead use [`CeSetUserNotificationEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms908105.aspx), which you can then query using the `CeGetUSerNotificationHandles` and `CeGetUserNotification` APIs